# Xcode cannot run using the selected device: xCode 4.2.1

Tags: xcode4

I'm testing with the Simulator and receive this error message. How do I select an appropriate (simulator) device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top left of the Xcode window you have a combobox containing all your targets. Select the iOS one, and then the appropriate Simulator. You should check that your iOS target has a 'Deployment Target' equal or lower than the Simulator version.

You can manage your Targets clicking at your project in the project navigator (left panel). After selecting the target, the 'Deployment Target' is under the 'Summary' and 'Build Options' tabs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I followed your instructions and changed Deployment Target from 5.1 to 5.0: it worked!